# Swift Reference to Outlet in subclass

Tags: ios, swift, subclass, superclass

I defined a `UITableViewController` connected to a storyboard as follows:

```
class systemwhereFilterCtrl: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

        @IBOutlet var mtableView: UITableView!
```

Then I used that class as a superclass:

```
class mychild : systemwhereFilterCtrl  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

When I start the view with `mychild` as controller and debug into `systemwhereFilterCtrl`, `mtableView` is `nil`.

Why isn't the table view from the superclass initialized?

To clearify: The nil comes in `systemwhereFilterCtrl`, when used as superclass

Answer (score 0):

You can access it directly using the `self` of the class. Likewise,

```
class mychild : systemwhereFilterCtrl  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.mtableView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not what i want. I only want that the tableview is loaded in UIViewcontroller with Controller mychild

Comment: self.mtableView would be nil too

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard is your view set to use the viewcontroller mychild? Also have you connected the tableview in the storyboard to that viewcontroller?

Comment: If you are asking question then please prefer comment because it's not an answer!

Comment: I have only connected in the systemwhereFilterCtrl

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
//...
self.mTableView = UITableView()
let tableView = self.mTableView
//...
}
```

Comment: hi niklas, don't want to init a tableview i want to reuse from superclass